# Making a Quaternion camera

Tags: java, opengl, camera, lwjgl, quaternions

I'd like to be able to create a camera which is first-person, and can be in one of two modes. Either it is fixed looking at a specific location (and standard "wasd" movement moves around that point), or it has free-look, where movement is not constrained to circling around a point and the mouse can be used to look anywhere. (clamped to only be able to look straight up/down though, as I don't want a six degrees of freedom camera a la Descent) This means that I currently do not want to have roll.

Can someone walk me through the basics necessary to implement this kind of thing? I'm currently using LWJGL, so I have access to the Vector* and Matrix* classes they provide, as well as my own Quaternion class which does some stuff that LWJGL doesn't. Also assume that I have a method, lookAt, which is given coordinates exactly like OpenGL's gluLookAt (eyex, eyey, ..., upy, upz), and this is where I wanted to build the matrix/matrices. Also assume the resultant matrix/matrices are going to be used in a version 330 shader where

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 model;
// ...
gl_Position = projection * camera * model * (position);
```

is some of the code. Do I keep the current order of operations, or do I need to change it in  any way to get the correct gl_Position?

Quaternion code:

```
public class Quaternion {
    public float x, y, z, w;

    public Quaternion() {
        this.x = 0.0f;
        this.y = 0.0f;
        this.z = 0.0f;
        this.w = 1.0f;
    }

    public Quaternion(Vector3f v, float w) {
        this.x = v.x;
        this.y = v.y;
        this.z = v.z;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public Quaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public Quaternion(Quaternion other) {
        this.x = other.x;
        this.y = other.y;
        this.z = other.z;
        this.w = other.w;
    }

    public float length() {
        return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z + w * w);
    }

    public Quaternion normalize() {
        return Quaternion.normalize(new Quaternion(this));
    }

    public Quaternion conjugate() {
        return Quaternion.conjugate(new Quaternion(this));
    }

    public Quaternion mult(Quaternion other) {
        return Quaternion.mult(this, other, new Quaternion());
    }

    public static Quaternion fromAxisAngle(Quaternion q, Vector3f axis, float angle) {
        float sinAngle2 = (float)Math.sin(angle / 2.0);
        q.x = axis.x * sinAngle2;
        q.y = axis.y * sinAngle2;
        q.y = axis.y * sinAngle2;
        q.w = (float)Math.cos(angle / 2.0);
        return q;
    }

    public static Matrix4f toMatrixUnit(Quaternion q) {
        Matrix4f ret = new Matrix4f();

        ret.m00 = 1 - 2 * q.y * q.y - 2 * q.z * q.z;
        ret.m01 = 2 * q.x * q.y - 2 * q.w * q.z;
        ret.m02 = 2 * q.x * q.z + 2 * q.w + q.y;
        ret.m03 = 0;

        ret.m10 = 2 * q.x * q.y + 2 * q.w * q.z;
        ret.m11 = 1 - 2 * q.x * q.x - 2 * q.z * q.z;
        ret.m12 = 2 * q.y * q.z + 2 * q.w * q.x;
        ret.m13 = 0;

        ret.m20 = 2 * q.x * q.z - 2 * q.w * q.z;
        ret.m21 = 2 * q.y * q.z - 2 * q.w * q.x;
        ret.m22 = 1 - 2 * q.x * q.x - 2 * q.y * q.y;
        ret.m23 = 0;

        ret.m30 = 0;
        ret.m31 = 0;
        ret.m32 = 0;
        ret.m33 = 1;

        return ret;
    }

    public static Matrix4f toMatrix(Quaternion q) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use toMatrixUnit");
//        Matrix4f ret = new Matrix4f();
//        return ret;
    }

    public static Quaternion mult(Quaternion A, Quaternion B, Quaternion C) {
        C.x = A.w*B.x + A.x*B.w + A.y*B.z - A.z*B.y;
        C.y = A.w*B.y - A.x*B.z + A.y*B.w + A.z*B.x;
        C.z = A.w*B.z + A.x*B.y - A.y*B.x + A.z*B.w;
        C.w = A.w*B.w - A.x*B.x - A.y*B.y - A.z*B.z;
        return C;
    }

    public static Quaternion normalize(Quaternion q) {
        float len = q.length();
        q.x = q.x / len;
        q.y = q.y / len;
        q.z = q.y / len;
        q.w = q.w / len;
        return q;
    }

    public static Quaternion conjugate(Quaternion q) {
        q.x = -q.x;
        q.y = -q.y;
        q.z = -q.z;
        return q;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of resources for implementing quaternion-based camera if you search Google.

- [Arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut08%20Quaternions.html) (be sure to click next etc.)
- [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-simple-quaternion-based-camera-r1997)
- [gpwiki](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation)

If you are in C++, I recommend using [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) (OpenGL Mathematics) for their vec/mat/quat support (if you are just learning, it beats having bugs in your arithmetic.)